# Programmatically detect and convert “pixel format not supported” images

Tags: c#, wpf

When I debug WPF apps with first-chance exception on, I got a lot of `NotSupportedException` with message “pixel format not supported”. If I ignore the exception, the images work just fine but I want to fix them anyway so I get a chance to look at other first-chance exceptions.

Currently I am looking into the callstack to figure out the file name, convert it manually using an image editor, and restart debugging to catch the next one. However, I wonder if I can automate this with a small console app to detect such images and convert them to the format that WPF is happy with.

I've read some references but with limited image knowledge I am unable to understand the exact problem WPF is having with these images, or how can I program it to detect these images as if they're loaded from XAML, or how to convert them programmatically to the format that WPF is happy with.

Comment: You mean, other than writing a tool that loads the images, catches the exception, and then converts the image? What format are you manually converting to, and what image editor are you doing it with?

Comment: @EricLaw I am struggling with the image knowledge instead of the other parts. I read up some references but couldn't understand what exact format is WPF happy/unhappy with, I only know if I open the file in Photoshop and save, without changing any image properties, the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you post a sample image that throws this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various file formats - PNG being one - where several different image formats are stored in the same file. In this case it's image depth (bits per pixel). So what .NET is probably doing is trying to open the file with the most common format first and when that fails it's trying different formats until it gets the one that works.

As this is a rare event it's sensible to just try to open the file and then trap the resultant exception and try again.

There's nothing you can really do about this as the exception is raised and (more importantly) handled within the image creation code.

You have encountered one of the big dangers of turning "first chance exception" on. You will get a number of these "false" errors. This mode should only be used for real problems you are encountering when you have no idea where an exception is being raised. As the image is read successfully you haven't really got an error case.

---

If .NET truly can't read the file format then you need need to trap the exception and do "something sensible" in the handler:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    try
    {
        // Your code to process the image
        var image = Image.Fromfile(file);
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException ex)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        process.Exited += ExitedHandler;
        // Call other app to convert file
        string arguments = file + command line arguments necessary
        process.Start(conversion program, arguments);
    }
```

`ExitedHandler` can call your code that processes the image so there's no need to loop over the converted files again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I am having difficulty with the image processing part, i.e. what should be inside the 'try' clause to simulate the same stack when the image is loaded in XAML, and what should be inside 'catch' to convert the image to a format that WPF accepts?

Comment: @NS.X. I assumed you were having problems with the catch part. What I have written is pretty much what you need. `conversion program` is the name of your image editor that you use manually. The arguments are the filename and the options necessary to do the conversion. As for the image load part, I guess just creating an `Image` would do.

Comment: I didn't mean to script the conversion tool - I am using Photoshop for that purpose now which is too heavy to loop with. Is there a way to do it purely in .NET code?

Comment: @NS.X. - well if .NET can't read the file format natively then you're going to have to use some other program (or perhaps 3rd party library) to do the conversion. You need this approach **because** .NET doesn't support all formats.

Comment: .NET can read it and the image works just fine, but with an first-chance exception.

Comment: @NS.X. - Ah. I think I understand now. I'll update the answer.